# SBT is unable to find credentials when attempting to download from an Artifactory virtual repo

Tags: scala, sbt, artifactory

I'm trying to run SBT behind a corporate firewall. Another team has configured an Artifactory proxy. This proxy works fine with anonymous access switched on, but when we make it require a password thinks start to go wrong.

When I run SBT on my workstation I get the following error:

```
[error] Unable to find credentials for [Artifactory Realm @ coderepo.xxx.amrs.bigco.com]
```

The result of this is that I cannot bootstrap sbt:

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.10.6: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;0.13.12: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.10.6: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

I've tried putting a .credentials file in ~/.sbt and also ~/.ivy2: I have been testing variations on the following, all of which do not work:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm @ coderepo.xxx.amrs.bigco.com
host=coderepo.xxx.amrs.bigco.com
user=<username>
password=<pwd>
```

I'm guessing that this error means that it was unable to locate a credentials definition that matched the realm, so I tried a number of versions of the first line in both locations:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
realm=[Artifactory Realm @ coderepo.xxx.amrs.bigco.com]
realm=coderepo.xxx.amrs.bigco.com
```

None of which seem to have any impact at all.

So what is the correct way to allow SBT to authenticate with username & password to a password protected Artifactory repository?

**UPDATE0**: According to the Ivy documentation, the most likely realm name is simply "Artifactory Realm". According to the SBT documentation, the correct default location of the credentials file should be %USERPROFILE%/.sbt/.credentials (yes, I'm using Windows). Even after deleting the .credentials file in my .ivy2 directory it still doesn't work.

**UPDATE1**: Relevant but not actually helpful:

- [SBT not passing credentials when publishing to Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497050/sbt-not-passing-credentials-when-publishing-to-artifactory)
- [Sbt can't authorize in Artifactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745569/sbt-cant-authorize-in-artifactory)

**UPDATE2**: I'm starting to suspect that this is a bug in sbt - I've added an issue here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/2817

Answer (score 24, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348805/how-to-access-a-secured-nexus-with-sbt) for details on how to configure global credentials.

To summarise:

If you need to boot SBT from a proxy repository, set the system property `sbt.boot.credentials` to point to your credentials file. You can do this in your `%CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86%/sbt/conf/sbtconfig.txt`, for example:

```
-Dsbt.boot.credentials=/Users/my-user-name/.sbt/credentials
```

Alternatively you can use the `SBT_CREDENTIALS` environment variable for the same purpose.

For Artifactory, the realm in the `credentials` file should be set to:

```
realm=Artifactory Realm
```

For authenticating dependency artifact retrieval, create a file like `%USERPROFILE%/.sbt/0.13/plugins/my-credentials.sbt` with a `credentials` setting. For example:

```scala
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / "credentials")
```

Comment: `export SBT_CREDENTIALS=some_credentials; sbt publish` is not enough. what you need is **1)** `credentials += Credentials(file("some_credentials"))` in `build.sbt`. or **2)** `credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")` in `~/.sbt/1.0/plugins/credentials.sbt`

Comment: @prayagupd Oh, you really saved me there! All the docs are just wrong.

Comment: @ViktorHedefalk glad to help. this might be helpful as well [publish a scala app with credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53069766/432903)

Comment: I had the same issue and was missing the credentials.sbt in the 1.0 folder.

Answer (score 5):

I think the default location for this file is `${HOME}/.sbt/<sbt-version>/.credentials`; while I trust there is published documentation on this, I confirmed this by clicking around in the code.
@salim-fadhley, looks like you are missing the SBT version in the path.

> **EDIT:** You need to add `DefaultOptions.addCredentials` to your build.sbt; you can then verify what SBT picks up with `show credentials`.

File location aside, there seems to be confusion between repository names (mean nothing) vs. security realms (mean everything).

The auth-challenge that comes back from the repository server will include the name of the *security realm*; as a client/developer, you have no control over what it is and my guess is it must match the *realm* you (client/developer) specify in your `.credentials` file (wherever that is).

Meanwhile, the repository name (as featured in `build.sbt`) actually means nothing to anyone outside development of the corresponding project e.g. the repository server admins could not care from one project to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Details about the environment -

```
Operating System - MacOS Catalina
    
exampleUser@exampleUser-mbp-2 plugins % sbt -version
sbt version in this project: 1.4.7
sbt script version: 1.4.7
    
exampleUser@exampleUser-mbp-2 plugins % scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.12 -- Copyright 2002-2017, LAMP/EPFL
```

User `HOME` directory -

```
exampleUser@exampleUser-mbp-2 plugins % echo $HOME
/Users/exampleUser
```

Location of `credentials.sbt` file - `$HOME/.sbt/1.0/plugins`

The `.credentials` file stores the `username/password` combination and is used by `Artifactory` for validation.
We should enter the location of the `.credentials` file in the `credentials.sbt` file.

An example entry is as follows -

```
exampleUser-mbp-2:plugins exampleUser$ cat $HOME/.sbt/1.0/plugins/credentials.sbt 
credentials += Credentials(Path.userHome / ".sbt" / ".credentials")
```