# How to pass credentials to sbt build cli?

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, dockerfile

I'm trying to Dockerize an old sbt build that needs access to a private nexus repo. I've previously been using a local credentials file referenced from the build.sbt, but that doesn't really fit my use currently since I want to bootstrap everything from a Dockerfile build. I rather not have to output stuff to a file and then copy it into my docker build container but rather just pass it as docker ARG's.

Under 
https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Publishing.html

I read I can pass it like so:

```
credentials += Credentials("Some Nexus Repository Manager", 
"my.artifact.repo.net", "admin", "admin123")
```

So therefore I figured I could do something like:

```
ARG REPO_USER
ARG REPO_PWD
RUN sbt ";credentials += Credentials(\"Some Nexus Repository Manager\", \"repo.host.com\", ${REPO_USER}, ${REPO_PWD}) ;package"
```

and then run

```
docker build . --build-arg REPO_USER=foobar --build-arg REPO_PWD=*****
```

in my Dockerfile but that didn't work. I still get:

Unable to find credentials for [Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager @ repo.host.com]

Is there any *nice* way to pass repo credentials to sbt from cli?

## Update:

I tried a a file approach but that didn't solve the problem so I guess I might be on the wrong track on what's actually wrong here.

```
RUN echo "realm=Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager" >> .credentials && \
echo "host=repo.host.se" >> .credentials && \
echo "user=$REPO_USER" >> .credentials && \
echo "password=$REPO_PWD" >> .credentials && \
export SBT_CREDENTIALS=.credentials && \
sbt package
```

## Update 2

I think this is no longer a Docker question at all since I've debugged it in the docker container sbt simply wouldn't pick my creds up any way I passed it according to the sbt docs.

I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Try `sbt ';set credentials ...'`

Comment: @laughedelic Still now luck. I also even tried using a cred file but it still didn't work so maybe I'm on the wrong track on what's actually wrong…

Comment: why u are storing crendentails in docker image

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan Don't want to, but need the creds for building since the build need access to private repo. Doing it with multi-stage builds and I think I can fix that security issue as soon as I just get it working at all. Suggestion?

Comment: do everything outside docker and then copy the results into docker image

Comment: @IjazAhmadKhan Point here is reproducible builds with _within_ docker. Like gitlab.ci drone.io.

Comment: yes , u can have reproducible builds , just do the builds in plain job and then trigger the docker build and use the artifact from previous job

Comment: > just do the builds in plain job 

what is a plain job? All jobs are defined from docker images on the mentioned build servers. To be super concrete, my build is from hseeberger/scala-sbt:11.0.1_2.12.7_1.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

The sbt docs are misleading at best or simply just wrong. After debugging this to bits in the docker container I found that there was no way I could pass the creds cli so they got picked up. The SBT_CREDENTIALS variable just doesn't work either.

This comment finally saved me: [SBT is unable to find credentials when attempting to download from an Artifactory virtual repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224921/sbt-is-unable-to-find-credentials-when-attempting-to-download-from-an-artifactor#comment89383700_40411532)

The least intrusive way I've got working is to add an sbt config file in the docker image's home dir:

```
RUN mkdir .sbt/0.13/plugins && \
echo "credentials += Credentials(\"Sonatype Nexus Repository Manager\", \"repo.host.se\", \"$REPO_USER\", \"$REPO_PWD\")" >> .sbt/0.13/plugins/creds.sbt
RUN sbt package
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variables. You can set them in dockerfile either straight or from args. Something like this:

```
ARG REPO_USR
ARG REPO_PWD

ENV REPO_USR = ${REPO_USR}
ENV REPO_PWD = ${REPO_PWD}
```

Then you can use the environment variables in sbt:

```
val repoUser = sys.env.get("REPO_USR").getOrElse("")
val repoPass = sys.env.get("REPO_PWS").getOrElse("")

credentials += Credentials("Repo Realm", "repo.url.com", repoUser, repoPass)
```

Then you can basically pass args to docker build and they will be passed on to sbt.

Comment: The problem with this is the second part, I guess you mean this as an edit of build.sbt. What I wanted was a way to _not_ have to edit the sbt build, but _only_ add a Dockerfile to the repo and pass creds CLI. The least intrusive way I've found is to let the Dockerfile add a separate sbt file under the image's $HOME/.sbt because there seems to be no way of passing creds to sbt without going through a file.