# Resolve java artifacts for sbt using settings.xml

Tags: java, scala, maven, sbt

I have projects implemented on scala/sbt and java/maven. Both use dependency someDependecy.jar which is hosted in artifactory.

To resolve path to artifactory for maven I've just added settings.xml into HOME/.m2.

Can I somehow tell sbt to use settings.xml to not to duplicate this urls and credentials to artifactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, if you want to resolve dependencies with sbt it uses under the hood ivy for dependency resolution. You cannot use settings.xml from maven. For sbt you need to specify ~/.sbt/repository and ~/.sbt/.credentials files to point to some dependency storage as JFrog as ir was mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224921/sbt-is-unable-to-find-credentials-when-attempting-to-download-from-an-artifactor) .

Answer (score 2):

I'd just add the artifactory location as a resolver into your build.sbt

```
resolvers += "my-artifactory" at "https://artifactory.host/groups/public"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "com.me" % "custom-dependency" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT", 
   "junit" % "junit" % "4.12" % "test"
)
```

Comment: This will be duplication. One in settings.xml one in sbt. I want to avoid this. But thanks.

Comment: Duplicate is not always evil, and there making SBT depends on Maven is not a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Look like XY; Rather than looking for a way to make SBT read maven specific config, it could recommended to check how to make it behave in similar way, like using dependency [resolver](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html).